# Spaces in newcommand

Tags: macros

I am trying to define a `\newcommand` which includes `\item*`(with no spaces before the asterisk) in the definition but when displaying the command I see that an extra space is placed thus preventing the moodle `multi` environment to work properly.

Is there anyway to prevent `\newcommand` to add this space?

This is an example of the code (compiled with `pdflatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\itemstar}{\item*}
\show\itemstar

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Hmmm... this smells a lot as an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. It would be much better to show the problem with the `multi` thing. (BTW, there is a `moodle` tag!)

Comment: there is no space token in the definition but tex shows a space after command names. Had you defined it as `\item *` then it would be an identical definition

Comment: As suspected, the problem is different --- @DavidCarlisle, I tried but I have been unable to expand just once  the `\answera` into the `multi` (which is basically an `itemize` list processed by `getitem` package).

Comment: You have completely changed the question after wipet had answered which isn't really considered good style on this network. Better to roll back the change, accept the answer to the original question and then ask a new one,

Comment: @E.M., please do as suggested by David in the previous comment... the problem is about delayed expansion and has nothing to do with spaces in commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX reads the text from file and tokenizes it. The control sequence (finished by space or not) is tokenized as one token followed by next token. The text `\item*` is tokenized as token[\item]token[*]. This pair of tokens is saved to the memory when the macro \itemstar is defined. When the contents of the macro is printed (by the `\show` primitive) then the two tokens is printed in standadized form: each control sequence token is followed by space.

You can write on input: `\item*` or `\item *`. Both cases are tokenized as token[\item]token[*] (there is no difference between them in TeX) and this pair of tokens is printed back as `\item *`.