# \newcommand and delayed expansion

Tags: macros

I would like to define a `\newcommand` which includes `\item*` (with no spaces in front of the asterisk) in the definition. Running this MWE:

```
% This moodle-test.tex file
% Run it with: pdflatex --shell-escape moodle-test.tex 
%
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{moodle}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\answera}{
  \item* One
  \item  Two
  \item  Three
}

\begin{quiz}{}
  \begin{multi}{Question A}
  Write 1 in letters
  \answera
  \end{multi}
\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

> No file moodle-test.aux.
>
> ! Package moodle Error: No correct answers given for multiple choice question..
>
> See the moodle package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.18   \end{multi}

as `\item*` was not properly propagated from `\newcommand` to the `multi` environment
(inlined code instead is working). Is the diagnosis correct? How to fix it?

Comment: The problem is not that `\item*` was not  properly propagated. The problem is that the way the `multi` environment works (via the `getitems` package) the text within the environment gets processed **as written** to check for `\item`s before other things. In particular, when it starts processing it only sees the macro `\answera` and not its expansion `\item .... \item .... \item ....`. If you edit your question to explain **why** you want to use `\answera` (which in the example shown does not serve any purpose) maybe someone can come up with a workaround.

Comment: isn't this identical to your last question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546089/spaces-in-newcommand ?

Comment: @WillieWong The reason why I want to use `\answera` is that I have already many problem sets with separate tex files for the questions and for the answers. Answer blocks are defined by `\answera` command and then imported in the main `document.tex` with the `\input` syntax. Now I need to export them into moodle with minimal editing to avoid typesetting mistakes.
@DavidCarlisle it is the same question as my understanding was to close that question and post a new one with the detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to force `\answera` to be expanded before inserting into the `multi` environment using `\expandafter`s. Most of the code below is dedicated to making it so that I don't have to type too many `\expandafter`s.

One note: the `getitems` package is pretty sensitive to the presence of extra spaces. Notice that I inserted a percent sign `%` and the end of the first line of `\newcommand{\answera}{%`. Without it, the compilation will fail.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{moodle}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\makemulti}[3]{\begin{multi}{#3} 
                #2 
                #1 
        \end{multi}}
\newcommand{\titlea}{Question A}
\newcommand{\questiona}{Write 1 in letters}
\newcommand{\answera}{%
  \item* One
  \item  Two
  \item  Three%
}

\begin{quiz}{}
        \expandafter\makemulti\expandafter{\answera}{\questiona}{\titlea}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```